# How to determine image file format with Python

Tags: python, image-processing

Recently, I need to write a python script that can verify integrity and determine the format of image files in detail. For example, for jpeg file it can tell the compress ratio, quality level, progressive or not; for png files, it can tell color mode.

It's there some existing python packages that can accomplish this task?

Comment: have you tried Python Imaging Library? http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: @hyleaus:  If using PIL I suggest using the excellent fork [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1) which supports Python 3 and has numerous improvements.